# I can't seem to create any instances because of CPU quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I just started my free trial of GCP and I see I have CPUs (all regions) globally set to 32.

When I start an instance (ex. 8 CPUs with 16GB of RAM) it says

`Quota 'N2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region europe-west4.`

Now, if I go to Quotas page and look up the N2 CPUs set for each region, this is set to 0 to ALL regions and I can't upgrade it because they won't accept the request.

This happens with all the CPUs available (N2D, N2, C2) so basically I can't start any instance.

Can anyone try to help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier): "You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time.". Do you have any other running VMs while tying to run this one?

Comment: Nope I don’t. I just started the free trial. :( Even if I create a VM with 8 N2D / N2 / C2 cores, it will still fail, whatever region I put.

Comment: Have you enabled billing?

Comment: Accordingly to the same documentation "You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see Resource quotas.". Are you able to use N1 VMs?

Comment: @JohnHanley How do I enable it? Actually I just started the free trial and nothing more. I'm able to access all the panels etc so I guess it's enabled.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza N1 start successfully. Why my friend is able to start N2 machines (doing my same free trial - we did it together while on chat on Discord) and I can't?

Comment: How to upgrade your account and enable billing: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade

Comment: Does your friend have enabled billing on his project?

Comment: I have enabled billing and so did my friend.

Comment: Did you enable billing before or after asking this question? If after, modify your question with current details.

Comment: No @JohnHanley , billing was already enabled before asking the question. :)

Comment: 1) Go to your billing account and verify that everything is setup. 2) More details needed for "I can't upgrade it because they won't accept the request".

Comment: I contacted the billing support and they told me that the billing and everything is successfully enabled. I filled 2 requests for increasing quotas for N2 or N2D (at least one) from 0 to 8 (Because I have them all set to 0.0 in ALL regions) and they clearly told me 'Please be informed that we are unable to proceed with your request, for this resource was quite high and needs capacity planning with our sales team. We recommend for you to contact sales team for capacity planning.' I did contact the sales team and they told me to start a free trial for my enterprise, which I already started!

Answer (score 3):

While using [12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) you have some limitations like:

> - You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time.
> - You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see [Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).
>
> You must [upgrade your account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) to perform any of the actions in
>   the preceding list.

To [request an increase in quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) you should follow steps below:

1. [Enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) for your account.
2. Go to [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page.
3. Select the quotas you want to change.
4. Click the Edit Quotas button and follow instructions to submit your request.

A support representative from the Compute Engine team will respond to your request within 24 to 48 hours. After that you'll get a confirmation that your request was approved, but in some cases your request could be declined for some reasons:

> Please be informed that we are unable to proceed with your request,
>   for this resource was quite high and needs capacity planning with our
>   sales team. We recommend for you to contact sales team for capacity
>   planning.

Accordingly to this reply, N2 vCPUs are on high demand at the moment and you should contact with [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to get your quota increased. There's no other way. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow community can do nothing in such cases.

Comment: It looks like "12-month $300 free trial" has reduced to "3-months $300 free trial": https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial